# Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary...when I just initialized a next app

Tags: next.js, client, next.js13, server-side, hydration

When I just started a next app, I got this error: [hydration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIM3Z.png)  Also there were other errors on the console: [missing action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poF6V.png)[router error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYpcu.png)
My layout.js:

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

My page.js:

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <h1>Hello Next</h1>
  );
}
```

I am using a Windows Operating System.

I have tried deleting the entire node modules and package-lock.json and running npm install again, only to still get back these errors when starting a new next project.

Comment: What's your Node.js version?